# RegEX - don't match lines that starts with a specific character

Tags: regex, vb6, match

I have a file like this:

```
-- START 
.
.
Err_EstensioneDatiClientiFornitori:
    Set ClsExtClifor = Nothing
    Set CallInterface = Nothing
    Call MsgError("EstensioneDatiClientiFornitori")
End Sub

 declare Cg44_clifor  decimal(8,0)
 declare Cg44_clifor  decimal(6,0)
' declare Cg44_clifor  decimal(6,0)
PC_CalcolaSaldoAllaData
PC_CalcolaSaldoMensileParziale
.
.
--END
```

I have to match only lines that contains `decimal(6,0)` but don't start with character `'`.

I've tried this regEx:

```
.*?decimal\(6,0\)
```

and I get two matches. First one:

```
 declare Cg44_clifor  decimal(6,0)
```

Second one:

```
' declare Cg44_clifor  decimal(6,0)
```

How can I exclude the second one? I don't want lines that starts with `'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough try this:

```
^[^'].*?decimal\(6,0\)
```

or even better version:

```
^(\s*[^']\s*)\w.*?decimal\(6,0\)
```

Will skip any white space before checking for single quote.

EDIT:

In case library matches on multiple lines, this should work:

```
^\s*[^'\n]\s*.*?decimal\(6,0\)
```

Comment: Hello, with the example file posted above and your regEx I get no results... with mine two... what's wrong?

Comment: I tested it in Notepad++, what tool do you use?

Comment: Expresso... I don't know if you know it.

Comment: Maybe it does not understand ^ than you're out of luck. You can test regular expressions on [http://regexpal.com/](http://tinyurl.com/9mtbxnr), please make sure to check `^$ match at line breaks`.

Comment: Do you know how can I do that `^$ match at line breaks` in VB6? It doesn't working...

Comment: It's a weird tool, this expression seems to work `^\s*[^'\n]\s*.*?decimal\(6,0\)`

Comment: Please read [this introduction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html) to regular expressions in VB6, you'll find there how to get multiple matches. Sorry I cannot test it myself as I don't have VB6 installed.

Comment: "It's a weird tool, this expression seems to work ^\s*[^'\n]\s*.*?decimal\(6,0\)"... seems to work where? If you are referring to Expresso doesn't work..

Comment: @epi82 Yes I was referring to Expresso, I tested the new expression on it. It worked.